# Display java string in xml textview

Tags: android, xml, string

This is my following java code, question is the xml id.  For some reason I keep on getting null whenever I try to print it out, is something wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private boolean correct;
private String questionTxt;

public int correctAnswer()
{
    int first = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    int second = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    int answer = first + second;
    questionTxt = first + " + " + second;
    return answer;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);

    TextView questionText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);
    questionText.setText(questionTxt + "");
}
```

xml code, just regular textview:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/question"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_above="@+id/option1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Comment: Show your xml codes pls

Comment: you are not calling `correctAnswer()` from anywhere, so your `questionTxt` is null

Comment: post full code here

Comment: Your problem isn't the XML

Comment: where do I call correctAnswer?

Comment: @cricket_007 thats the reason I didn't provide the xml code at first, but provided it on request

Comment: just right before you need to access that String questionTxt

Comment: Obviously call it  before you try to set the text if you don't want to see null

Comment: before  questionText.setText(questionTxt + "");

Comment: OH          i see lol I get it now

Comment: dangit I make this mistake every time in class too

Comment: Who is going to answer for this difficult question ??

Comment: thanks for the help

Comment: are you sure above `TextView` inside `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` MainActivity layout ?

Comment: um I didn't understand that question

Comment: How do I make the font bigger?

Comment: @LarryJing To make font bigger  `android:textSize="15sp"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call this method correctAnswer(); before setting value into textview

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private boolean correct;
private String questionTxt;

public int correctAnswer()
{   
int first = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
int second = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
int answer = first + second;
questionTxt = first + " + " + second;
return answer;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);

correctAnswer();
TextView questionText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);
questionText.setText(questionTxt + "");
}
```

Comment: @LarryJing if you got the answer vote for this question it may useful to someone

Comment: I have to wait one minute to accept it and my vote doesn't count publicly since I only have 10 reputation XD

Answer (score 0):

You should move the method after onCreate

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private boolean correct;
    private String questionTxt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
        TextView questionText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);
        int answer = correctAnswer();
        questionText.setText(answer+");

    }

    public int correctAnswer()
    {
        int first = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
        int second = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
        int answer = first + second;
        questionTxt = first + " + " + second;
        return answer;
    }
 }
```